# Unable to loop in SuperH assembly if counter range exceeds two's complement signed range

Tags: assembly

I wrote some SuperH assembly code that draws an image:

```
# image width
mov.b @r6+, r11
# image height
mov.b @r6+, r12

# draw image
# (code omitted for brevity)
#

# increment x counter by 2 (drawing two pixels at a time)
  add #2, r7
# check the loop counter against image width
  cmp/eq r7, r11 
  bf draw_image_loop

# (y loop code omitted)
```

This works perfectly with width 126, but not 128. This tells me perhaps the cmp/eq is treating r11 and possibly other registers as signed data.

From the SH-2 manual:

`CMP/EQ Rm,Rn If Rn = Rm, 1 → T`

Other instructions explicitly mention signed data, so I'm assuming that cmp/eq therefore is implicitly unsigned, but with my code not working, perhaps not.

How do I fix this? I generally want to treat all my data as unsigned unless I explicitly want to define signed integers.

Comment: For equality it should not matter. Only for less/greater. I haven't checked but the `add` is more likely to cause problems if that is using saturation for example.

Comment: It shouldn't matter right? But when the image width is 128 or higher, it looks like I don't ever return from the image draw subroutine. So something is going wrong with that comparison.

Comment: `mov.b` is using sign extension. Try `movu.b`.

Comment: SH-2 manual does not specify a movu or movu.b instruction, and gnu assembler errors with: invalid operands for opcode

Comment: Then try an `extu.b r11, r11` after the load.